# How can I read a UTF-8 text file from a jar using the Java method Class.getResourceAsStream()?

Tags: java, text, jar, utf-8, inputstreamreader

I have a UTF-8 file stored inside a java jar file. I am trying to read it using the method getResourceAsStream(), but the input stream reader that is returned by the function uses the default encoding, which is the ANSI one under Windows.

How can I read a UTF-8 text file from inside a jar?

Answer (score 10):

Create an `InputStreamReader` around the `InputStream`, specifying UTF-8 as the encoding.

Note: I'm not sure what you mean by "the input stream reader that is returned by the function uses the default encoding" - `getResourceAsStream()` returns an `InputStream`, which reads *binary* data. That's not a *reader* at all (dealing with character data).

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck looking at the return type of getResourceAsStream and thinking that it returns an InputStreamReader, whereas it returns an InputStream. That's what you get if you program while tired :-).

Answer (score 0):

native2ascii may help you.
it converts non-ascii characters to equivalent character codes inside your utf-8 file.
for example;
`native2ascii -encoding Cp1254 input_file.txt output_file.properties`
enjoy...